# How to make matching schema for two data frame in join without hard coding for every columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frame on which I perform join and some time i get below error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN (`IsAnnualReported_1` IS NOT NULL) THEN `IsAnnualReported_1` ELSE CAST(`IsAnnualReported` AS BOOLEAN) END' due to data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;;
```

Now to overcome this i have to manually cast into to matching data types like below for all machinating data type columns .

```
when($"IsAnnualReported_1".isNotNull, $"IsAnnualReported_1").otherwise($"IsAnnualReported".cast(DataTypes.BooleanType)).as("IsAnnualReported"),
```

This is how i perform join on two data frames .

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
    import java.sql.{Date, Timestamp}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_extract

val get_cus_val = spark.udf.register("get_cus_val", (filePath: String) => filePath.split("\\.")(3))
val get_cus_YearPartition = spark.udf.register("get_cus_YearPartition", (filePath: String) => filePath.split("\\.")(4))

val df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").option("inferSchema","true").load("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialPeriod/MAIN")

val df1With_ = df.toDF(df.columns.map(_.replace(".", "_")): _*)
val column_to_keep = df1With_.columns.filter(v => (!v.contains("^") && !v.contains("!") && !v.contains("_c"))).toSeq
val df1result = df1With_.select(column_to_keep.head, column_to_keep.tail: _*)
val df1resultFinal=df1result.withColumn("DataPartition", get_cus_val(input_file_name))
val df1resultFinalWithYear=df1resultFinal.withColumn("PartitionYear", get_cus_YearPartition(input_file_name))


val df2 = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").option("inferSchema","true").load("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialPeriod/INCR")
val df2With_ = df2.toDF(df2.columns.map(_.replace(".", "_")): _*)
val df2column_to_keep = df2With_.columns.filter(v => (!v.contains("^") && !v.contains("!") && !v.contains("_c"))).toSeq
val df2result = df2With_.select(df2column_to_keep.head, df2column_to_keep.tail: _*)



import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("FinancialPeriod_organizationId", "FinancialPeriod_periodId").orderBy($"TimeStamp".cast(LongType).desc) 
val latestForEachKey = df2result.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec)).filter($"rank" === 1).drop("rank", "TimeStamp")

df1resultFinalWithYear.printSchema()
latestForEachKey.printSchema()

val dfMainOutput = df1resultFinalWithYear.join(latestForEachKey, Seq("FinancialPeriod_organizationId", "FinancialPeriod_periodId"), "outer")
      .select($"FinancialPeriod_organizationId", $"FinancialPeriod_periodId",
        when($"DataPartition_1".isNotNull, $"DataPartition_1").otherwise($"DataPartition".cast(DataTypes.StringType)).as("DataPartition"),
        when($"PartitionYear_1".isNotNull, $"PartitionYear_1").otherwise($"PartitionYear".cast(DataTypes.StringType)).as("PartitionYear"),
        when($"FinancialPeriod_periodEndDate_1".isNotNull, $"FinancialPeriod_periodEndDate_1").otherwise($"FinancialPeriod_periodEndDate").as("FinancialPeriod_periodEndDate"),
        when($"FinancialPeriod_periodStartDate_1".isNotNull, $"FinancialPeriod_periodStartDate_1").otherwise($"FinancialPeriod_periodStartDate").as("FinancialPeriod_periodStartDate"),
        when($"FinancialPeriod_periodDuration_1".isNotNull, $"FinancialPeriod_periodDuration_1").otherwise($"FinancialPeriod_periodDuration").as("FinancialPeriod_periodDuration"),
        when($"FinancialPeriod_nonStandardPeriod_1".isNotNull, $"FinancialPeriod_nonStandardPeriod_1").otherwise($"FinancialPeriod_nonStandardPeriod").as("FinancialPeriod_nonStandardPeriod"),
        when($"FinancialPeriod_periodType_1".isNotNull, $"FinancialPeriod_periodType_1").otherwise($"FinancialPeriod_periodType").as("FinancialPeriod_periodType"),
        when($"PeriodFiscalYear_1".isNotNull, $"PeriodFiscalYear_1").otherwise($"PeriodFiscalYear").as("PeriodFiscalYear"),
        when($"PeriodFiscalEndMonth_1".isNotNull, $"PeriodFiscalEndMonth_1").otherwise($"PeriodFiscalEndMonth").as("PeriodFiscalEndMonth"),
        when($"IsAnnualReported_1".isNotNull, $"IsAnnualReported_1").otherwise($"IsAnnualReported".cast(DataTypes.BooleanType)).as("IsAnnualReported"),
        when($"IsTransitional_1".isNotNull, $"IsTransitional_1").otherwise($"IsTransitional".cast(DataTypes.StringType)).as("IsTransitional"),
        when($"CumulativeType_1".isNotNull, $"CumulativeType_1").otherwise($"CumulativeType").as("CumulativeType"),
        when($"CalendarizedPeriodEndDate_1".isNotNull, $"CalendarizedPeriodEndDate_1").otherwise($"CalendarizedPeriodEndDate").as("CalendarizedPeriodEndDate"),
        when($"EarliestAnnouncementDateTime_1".isNotNull, $"EarliestAnnouncementDateTime_1").otherwise($"EarliestAnnouncementDateTime").as("EarliestAnnouncementDateTime"),
        when($"EADUTCOffset_1".isNotNull, $"EADUTCOffset_1").otherwise($"EADUTCOffset").as("EADUTCOffset"),
        when($"PeriodPermId_1".isNotNull, $"PeriodPermId_1").otherwise($"PeriodPermId").as("PeriodPermId"),
        when($"PeriodPermId_objectTypeId_1".isNotNull, $"PeriodPermId_objectTypeId_1").otherwise($"PeriodPermId_objectTypeId").as("PeriodPermId_objectTypeId"),
        when($"PeriodPermId_objectType_1".isNotNull, $"PeriodPermId_objectType_1").otherwise($"PeriodPermId_objectType").as("PeriodPermId_objectType"),
        when($"CumulativeTypeId_1".isNotNull, $"CumulativeTypeId_1").otherwise($"CumulativeTypeId").as("CumulativeTypeId"),
        when($"PeriodTypeId_1".isNotNull, $"PeriodTypeId_1").otherwise($"PeriodTypeId").as("PeriodTypeId"),
        when($"PeriodFiscalEndMonthId_1".isNotNull, $"PeriodFiscalEndMonthId_1").otherwise($"PeriodFiscalEndMonthId").as("PeriodFiscalEndMonthId"),
        when($"PeriodLengthUnitId_1".isNotNull, $"PeriodLengthUnitId_1").otherwise($"PeriodLengthUnitId").as("PeriodLengthUnitId"),
        when($"FFAction_1".isNotNull, concat(col("FFAction_1"), lit("|!|"))).otherwise(concat(col("FFAction"), lit("|!|"))).as("FFAction"))
        .filter(!$"FFAction".contains("D"))
```

Now what I need is that, how can I create second data frame with the schema of first data frame so i will never get any error like data type mismatch .

Here is the schema of first and second data frame

```
root
 |-- FinancialPeriod_organizationId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPeriod_periodId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPeriod_periodEndDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPeriod_periodStartDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPeriod_periodDuration: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPeriod_nonStandardPeriod: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPeriod_periodType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodFiscalYear: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodFiscalEndMonth: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- IsAnnualReported: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsTransitional: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- CumulativeType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CalendarizedPeriodEndDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EarliestAnnouncementDateTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- EADUTCOffset: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodPermId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodPermId_objectTypeId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodPermId_objectType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CumulativeTypeId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodTypeId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodFiscalEndMonthId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodLengthUnitId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- FFAction: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DataPartition: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PartitionYear: string (nullable = true)
root
 |-- DataPartition_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PartitionYear_1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPeriod_organizationId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPeriod_periodId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPeriod_periodEndDate_1: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPeriod_periodStartDate_1: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPeriod_periodDuration_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPeriod_nonStandardPeriod_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPeriod_periodType_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodFiscalYear_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodFiscalEndMonth_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsAnnualReported_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsTransitional_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CumulativeType_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CalendarizedPeriodEndDate_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EarliestAnnouncementDateTime_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EADUTCOffset_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodPermId_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodPermId_objectTypeId_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodPermId_objectType_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CumulativeTypeId_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodTypeId_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodFiscalEndMonthId_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodLengthUnitId_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FFAction_1: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: If you change the second dataframe's column names as that of first dataframe then you will have problems after you join them as there would be duplicate column names and would cause problems for when condition that you are using.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes but can we not only change the data type ?

Comment: if you want to update the dataType, you would need to know the mapping of both dataframes column names. when you have them then you write a query to change them :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I know the name of the columns of both data frames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a good solution .

Here I am going to show you how you can avoid writing manually each *columns* for *typecasting*.

Lets say you have two `dataframes` (as you already have them) as

```
df1
root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)

df2
root
 |-- cl2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- cl1: integer (nullable = false)
```

suppose you want to change the `dataTypes` of `df2` as that of `df1`. and as you said you know the mapping of each *columns* of both `dataframes`. You have to create `Map` of the relationship of the *columns*

```
val columnMaps = Map("col1" -> "cl1", "col2"->"cl2")
```

When you have the `map` as above, you can set the `dataTypes` to be casted to each *columns* of `df2` as below

```
val schema1 = df1.schema
val toBeChangedDataTypes =df1.schema.map(x => if(columnMaps.keySet.contains(x.name)) (columnMaps(x.name), x.dataType) else (x.name, x.dataType)).toList
```

Then you can change the `dataTypes` of the *columns* of `df2` to match with `df1` by calling a *recursive* function

```
val finalDF = castingFunction(toBeChangedDataTypes, df2)
```

where `castingFunction` is a *recursive* function defined as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
def castingFunction(typeList: List[Tuple2[String, DataType]], df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = typeList match {
  case x :: y => castingFunction(y, df.withColumn(x._1, col(x._1).cast(x._2)))
  case Nil => df
}
```

You will see that `finalDF` will have schema as

```
root
 |-- cl2: string (nullable = false)
 |-- cl1: integer (nullable = false)
```

You can do the same for your dataframes.

I hope the answer is helpful